# Laravel 5.8 View [admin.home] not found on live site

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-views

my laravel site is working fine on localhost but not working on live domain after i upload my site on hosting.

I cleared my cache from online, check my routes again but nothing change.

MY ROUTES:

```
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function ()         {
         Route::get('/', 'HomeController@home')->name('admin.home');
   //    Route::resource('/', 'DashboardController');
         Route::resource('school_account', 'SchoolAccountController');
         Route::get('school_account/{school_account}/update_status', 'SchoolAccountController@update_status')->name('school_account.update_status');
         Route::resource('package', 'PackageController');
         Route::resource('license', 'LicenseController');
         Route::resource('feature', 'FeatureController');
     });
```

> my Controller Class

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

 class HomeController extends Controller
 {
     public function home()
     {
         return view('admin.home');
     }
 }
```

directory of blades:

Comment: what is real error? admin.home view not found or admin.home route not found?

Comment: incomplete question

Comment: admin.home not found.

Comment: it's may incomplete if there is any issue to understanding please edit my question....

Comment: but in question title this is mentioned view [admin.home] not found you can read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are developing on a Windows machine and host your website on a Linux machine?

On Windows, folders are case insensitive, meaning that `Admin` and `admin` are the same folder. However, on Linux, paths are case sensitive and those paths are not the same.

Rename your `views/Admin` folder to `views/admin` and all should be fixed.

Comment: I jsut change from my controller 
    "return view('admin.home');" 
to 
    "return view('Admin.home');"

Comment: Glad I could help, consider marking this as the answer to your question so other users might find this as well.

Comment: this answer is helpful and helps solve my view not found issue

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your view file exist on server.

`<project-root>/resources/views/admin/home.blade.php`

And try to clear the view cache.

`php artisan view:clear`

Comment: i said on live site how do i clear cach using artisan command ?

Comment: Do you have shell access of hosting?

Comment: If not create an api that could run the `artisan` command internally